# Why does Gmail still only show email address when I have that person's name in my contacts?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

When looking at my Gmail inbox some emails show the contact name in the from column and others just show an email address.  The strange thing is that some of the ones that just show email address are ones that I do have their full name in my contacts.

When I highlight over the email address it shows the popup with their Contact card including their name and picture, etc.

Does anyone know why these just show up as email address and are not rendered as the person's name?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, Gmail always shows the contact information that is included in the mail. F.e. if someone sends you an e-mail from `"Foo Bar <foo@bar.com>"`, and you have that person in your contacts under the name `"Lovely Fee <foo@bar.com>"`, it will still show the information Foo decided itself to include in the mail.

I believe that there is a Userscript that changes this for you, but I cannot find it now.

This is a choice Gmail makes, probably to avoid ambiguity between contacts. Perhaps they will sometime decide to change this behavior.

Comment: 7 years later and they still haven't decided to change this ridicules 'feature'.